# Laravel saving data with Carbon::now() is formatted differently to created_at

Tags: php, laravel, date, datetime, php-carbon

I'm working with a Laravel project and time zones (I know time zones are a pain), and what's occurred to be is that one of my custom columns in my table, the column called `last_checked` which is stored as a `timestamp` appears to be formatted differently from the `created_at`, and it means that my time zone parsing isn't parsing the date at all for the user's time zone.

Here's what I mean...

When storing a record, I set the date and time:

```php
$uptimeMonitor = Monitors::where('id', $monitor['id'])
                           ->get()
                           ->first();

$uptimeMonitor->last_checked = Carbon::now();
$uptimeMonitor->save();
```

But when I retrieve the result, looking in my network request, I'm seeing this format:

> 2021-04-05 11:46:54

But when I look at both the `created_at` and `updated_at` columns, they're in this format:

> 2021-04-05T10:01:16.000000Z

So the question here is, what am I doing wrong with saving my data? Both formats seem to be visually shown the same in the database, but for some strange reason, the first example isn't parsing correctly.

Comment: use `NOW()` method to get current date.

Comment: That's what I'm currently doing?

Comment: `Carbon::now()` is different from `NOW()` method

Comment: `Carbon::now()` is completely fine here. So your PHP config (and not the DB one) is driving the time synchronization. (And so you can mock it in unit tests.) Don't use SQL `NOW()`, it's wrong and won't solve your problem. By the way, UTC should be your default timezone everywhere: config/app.php and DB timezone.

Answer (score 0):

Carbon uses the default **DateTime** PHP object, so use the **date_default_timezone_set()** function, for example: date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

or you define it `AppServiceProvider` `App/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`

```
public function boot()
{
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
}
```

Or you can use `setTimezone` of carbon method

```
echo Carbon::now()->setTimezone('UTC')->format('H:i');
```

Try this

```
$uptimeMonitor = Monitors::where('id', $monitor['id'])
                           ->get()
                           ->first();

$uptimeMonitor->last_checked = Carbon::now()->setTimezone('UTC')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$uptimeMonitor->save();
```

> Note my default app timezone is `UTC` just find your default timezone
> and set it in `setTimezone('UTC');

Answer (score 0):

You need to add all the datetime properties in your `$casts` model protected member:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#date-casting

All is OK in your DB, it's just Laravel model has to know it's a date to format with the full ISO-8601 string in your JSON.

Side note, you still should have "UTC" as your default in config/app.php, it does not prevent from having any timezone handling for particular cases, or to handle users timezone, on the contrary.

If your dates output string as GMT+1 by default, it's very likely a configuration mistake.

Comment: The reason my Laravel's config is now `Europe/London` is because with it being `UTC`, the datetime entries in the DB were an hour out when British Summer Time kicked in, so all the DB values would be off by one hour

Comment: And so what? This actually not even a reason. UTC is the way to represent universally the time so any system/back-end should use it, not a city timezone which bound your app to it while it could be agnostic from it and certainly not a timezone with DST which will lead to tons of bugs. Your Laravel's config AND your DB should both be in UTC. But still your issue is not related to timezone, just to cast/format. I don't know what kind of miracle you are waiting for but this above is your solution.